# About Timeout option for the telnet in windows 2003

Tags: windows, windows-2003-webserver

Task: On a list of nodes i want to check are those telnet reachable through port 8080 or not with out using name/password from windows 2003 machine.

problem: It is taking to long time for getting out of prompt(some time it seems like hanging).

Thanks in advance.
kishore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really to do with the behaviour of the TCP/IP stack rather than that of telnet.exe (or any other high-level application).

Have a look at [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314053) from Microsoft - search it for `TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions` - and you might be able to cut it down to max 3 seconds per host, but I can't find any way to further reduce that 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dave, but i am not in a possition that i can't change those parameters because other scripts/users will get effected. and one more thing is i am doing this check with command "telnet <ip_address of node> 13014" in a script. Actual problem here is with some nodes connection is opening with out asking any credentials and not comming out from that prompt. please help me from this chalenges! Thanks a ton in advance..

Comment: How are your trying to do this? With a batch file or with a scripting language of some kind? I think you would need to use a scripting language that can make raw TCP socket connections, rather than trying use telnet.exe, since what you are describing is an unavoidable problem with this setup.

Comment: Thanks Dave, you are right i am doing this in a perl script but twist here is my machine is windows 2003 machine with active perl hope i have to install cygwin environment perl for solving my problem.

Comment: I know it's not exactly ideal, but I could do something like this in PHP core (no extensions) in 5 minutes - Perl is a great language but on Windows you're fighting a losing battle...